# MetPy vs Pint package compatibility error

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, metpy, pint

In my Conda environment, when I run `pip show MetPy`, my first and last two lines are:

```
Name: MetPy
Version: 1.0
...
Requires: scipy, matplotlib, pandas, pyproj, pooch, importlib-resources, traitlets, importlib-metadata, numpy, pint, xarray
Required-by:
```

When I run `pip show pint`, my first and last two lines are:

```
Name: Pint
Version: 0.16.1
...
Requires: packaging, importlib-metadata
Required-by: MetPy
```

These should be the latest versions of these packages. Yet, when I try to do...

```
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
```

...I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redacted.py", line 17, in <module>
    import metpy.calc as mpcalc
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/metpy/calc/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .cross_sections import *  # noqa: F403
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/metpy/calc/cross_sections.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .tools import first_derivative
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/metpy/calc/tools.py", line 106, in <module>
    def find_intersections(x, a, b, direction='all', log_x=False):
  File "~/anaconda3/envs/environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pint/registry_helpers.py", line 248, in decorator
    % (func.__name__, count_params, len(args))
TypeError: find_intersections takes 5 parameters, but 3 units were passed
```

This makes me think I'm missing something with my package updates. Is there another dependency I'm missing?

Comment: Please please please tag anaconda questions as [tag:anaconda] and pip questions as [tag:pip]. This issue likely has zero to do with the specific packages, so the question title is misleading.

Comment: **If these packages were installed with conda not pip, you should have used `conda show <package-name>` not `pip show...`.** It's quite possible you have conflicting versions of a package installed, one under conda, one under pip. (and the obvious way to check that is to uninstall the one(s) installed with pip). Downvoting for confusion.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I’ve been installing through pip and I believe that muddled everything. Installing a new environment from scratch solely through conda-forge seems to have solved things. Sorry for not using those tags. I have a relationship with the MetPy folks so directed this at them. Newbie poster move. This can be closed, when I figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It appears likely that you might not have `pip` installed within your conda environment or that you are running `pip` from somewhere outside your conda environment, and so `pip show` might be misleading you. Check your versions of MetPy and Pint within your conda environment with `conda list`, as this should be a version conflict error between older versions of MetPy (<=0.11.1) and newer versions of Pint (>0.9).

`conda install -c conda-forge metpy==1.0` should get your conda environment caught up to MetPy 1.0.